# How to Include a Text Version of Email in JAVA

Tags: jakarta-mail, html-email, spam, sendgrid

I am sending emails through java web application, Emails contains only html content. Emails sent to recipients are landing in SPAM folder for particularly one domain (ex: mydomain.com).

So, When i searched for the solution it says that, Emails must also contain plain version, So how to include the plain version as well in html mails in java, My emails also contains attachments.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, Its working fine.

```
String body ="<html><head></head><body><span>this is a test mail</span></body></html>           

Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");   // Create an "Alternative" Multipart message

            MimeBodyPart text = new MimeBodyPart();
            MimeBodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();

            text.setText(body.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","").replaceAll("&nbsp;","").replaceAll("&amp;","&"));  //set the text/plain version
            html.setContent(Jsoup.parse(body).html(), "text/html");     //set the text/html version

            multiPart.addBodyPart(text);
            multiPart.addBodyPart(html); 
            message.setContent(multiPart);
```

Answer (score 1):

This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpa) will help you with everything except the attachment part.  Try this simple version first and get that working before you move on.

This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#attach) talks about attachments.

You need to combine both.  You need to create a message with a multipart/mixed content to hold the main body and attachments.  The first body part should be the multipart/alternative content instead of just a plain text part.

Let me know if that's not enough to get you started.